# Terminal not recognizing imacro:// as protocol, thinks it's a pathname

Tags: terminal

I'm trying to run this from the terminal:

```
open /Applications/Firefox.app imacros://run/?m=macro.iim
```

This gives me the error

```
The file /Users/dave/Desktop/watch-nodejs/imacros:/run/?m=macro.iim does not exist.
```

The expected result is to open firefox and type "imacros://run/?m=macro.iim" in the url bar. This works on mac and windows, but for some reason mac thinks "imacros://run/?m=macro.iim" is a path to a file on my computer

Answer (score 4):

Use

```
open /Applications/Firefox.app --args 'imacros://run/?m=macro.iim'
```

to prevent `open` from messing with the argument. Also quoting might help to stop the shell from stumbling over any special characters (not really required in this specific case).

Comment: It is not open messing with the arguments surely it is just passing the second string (imacro...)  to open and not to Firefox